Lookup a value when another column matches another value
I am trying to do a standard vlookup but only when another column matches the value in a specific cell.
I have a standard lookup that is
=VLOOKUP(A2,'For Reporting'!B:G,6,FALSE)
But I want it to do this only when column A in sheet 'For Reporting' matches the value in G$1
Can anyone help me with this please.
Please don't laugh, I tried this
=(VLOOKUP(A2,'For Reporting'!B:G,6,FALSE)&IF('For Reporting'!A:A,Data!G1))
But just get a spill error.

You're nearly there, just wrap the IF function around the VLOOKUP:
=IF('For Reporting'!A:A=G1 , VLOOKUP(A:A,'For Reporting'!B:G,6,FALSE) , "")

You can alternatively add in a text between the "", which will display when no result is found OR even add in another search formula.
The above formula will fill in for all cells in the column. Check below for more options.
Hope that helps, let me know if something is unclear.

=IF('For Reporting'!A2=$G$1 , VLOOKUP(A2,'For Reporting'!B:G,6,FALSE) , "")

This variant will only lookup whatever is in cell A2, IF A2 equals G1; however if you drag it down, say to A3, it will check A3 with G1 and return a value.

A third option, which is a bit of an in between:
=IF('For Reporting'!Ax:Ay=$G$1 , VLOOKUP(Ax:Ay,'For Reporting'!B:G,6,FALSE) , "")

This works like dragging it down, but you can determine the range, by changing x and y into actual values, say your range is A2 till A15, then use this:
=IF('For Reporting'!A2:A15=$G$1 , VLOOKUP(A2:A15,'For Reporting'!B:G,6,FALSE) , "")


Many thanks for helping out. Quick question. Not sure why you have changed the lookup value from A2 to A:A but have tried it both ways and still get a spill error, any idea what i've done wrong?

@SteveMortlock make sure the entire column below is empty (all cells must be empty); hope that resolves the SPILL issue. The formula will fill down the entire column, this also answers your question. (let me add that in the original answer).

It doesn't like the whole column reference as soon as I change to A2:A10000 it works perfectly. Many thanks for the help.
